# Scheduling a sqoop job in oozie through Shell script using Hue

Tags: shell, hadoop, sqoop, oozie, hue

I am able to run a sqoop command in Oozie using Hue. But, when I try to run the same sqoop command by placing it in a shell script I am getting an error like below

```
Stdoutput 2016-05-20 10:52:13,241 ERROR [main] sqoop.Sqoop (Sqoop.java:runSqoop(181)) - Got exception running Sqoop: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I have included the jdbc jar file like I did while running the sqoop command directly. I don't understand why it is not working for shell script.

Here is the workflow generated by Hue

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="shell-ca31"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="shell-ca31">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>default</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                    <value>/user/oozie/libext</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>sqoopoozie.sh</exec>
            <file>/user/yxr6907/sqoopoozie.sh#sqoopoozie.sh</file>
            <archive>/user/oozie/libext/ojdbc7.jar#ojdbc7.jar</archive>
              <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Where is the driver located relative to the script?

Comment: Did you put the driver in the 'lib' folder of the workflow?

Comment: @Romain I updated the question with the workflow xml and Yes the driver is in the location that is specified in the workflow.

Comment: Have you found any work around? I am having similar issue.

Comment: @yAsH Can we schedule multiple sqoop jobs in oozie to run in parallel. If yes how can we do that please let me know

Comment: I have the same issue. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use shell action, jars for sqoop are not imported into classpath.
I was able to solve it by adding the jar into the classpath. Then, i export HADOOP_CLASSPATH and sqoop works.

Use the following:

1. Put the jar `ojdbc7.jar` in files
2. Use the following command inside shell script: `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${PWD}/ojdbc7.jar`

Instead of step 1. you can use the following properties to load jar into classpath:

```bash
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/path/to/jars
```

Exporting HADOOP_CLASSPATH is required in both ways.